# BASH: Math with variable filled with data from Text file (Resolved)

Tags: bash

I have spent some time trying and googling for the solution with no success.
I have a text file, "file.txt" (Unix, BOM, LF) that contains 3 numbers, as follows:

7896763907428
40040000
14

I just need to do a simple math here:

```
7896763907428 + (40040000 * 14)
```

Doing that directly in bash (using Cygwin, btw) it works just fine:

```
echo $((7896763907428 + 40040000 * 14))
7897324467428
```

if I manually load the values into variables, it also works:

```
a=7896763907428
b=40040000
c=14

echo $((a + b * c))
7897324467428
```

However, if those values are in text file and I use them to do the math, it fails:

```
a=$(sed -n 1p auxFile.txt)
b=$(sed -n 2p auxFile.txt)
c=$(sed -n 3p auxFile.txt)
echo $((a + b * c))
bash: 7896763907428: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "7896763907428")
```

I've loaded the value using other methods, but they bring the same result.
The weird stuff is that the failure happens only on $a, the math on $b and $b works.

```
echo $((b * c))
560560000
echo $((b + c))
40040014
```

EDIT:
Original file came from windows PS exported as UTF8 option that end like been UTF8 + BOM that includes some data at the beginning of the file. Have used dos2unix tool to convert the text file before process it on linux.

Comment: Please post the output of `hexdump -C auxFile.txt`? Please add `set -x` and post debugging output from script execution.

Comment: Are the 3 numbers separated by spaces, or newlines?

Comment: hexdump out
0000000 bbef 38bf 3138 3534 3432 3835 3534 3034
0000010 340a 3030 3034 3030 0a30 3431 310a 3136
0000020 3232 3630 3938 3034 3838 7469 6d65 302d
0000030 6935 6574 0a6d
0000036

Comment: Script execution with set -x:
++ _bbf sed -n 1p auxFile.txt
++ '[' -e /bin/sed.exe ']'
++ '[' -e /bin/sed ']'
++ sed -n 1p auxFile.txt
+ a=$'\357\273\2778814524584540'
++ _bbf sed -n 2p auxFile.txt
++ '[' -e /bin/sed.exe ']'
++ '[' -e /bin/sed ']'
++ sed -n 2p auxFile.txt
+ b=40040000
++ _bbf sed -n 3p auxFile.txt
++ '[' -e /bin/sed.exe ']'
++ '[' -e /bin/sed ']'
++ sed -n 3p auxFile.txt
+ c=14

Comment: I ended up finding the problem in hard way while the above suggestions would have lead me to the problem earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are processing a file, awk maybe a better alternative:

```
awk '{ print $1 + ($2 * $3) }' file
```

Multiply the second space delimited field by the third and then add the first.

Comment: awk output:
0
40004000
14

Answer (score 0):

#### Numbers on single line (`1 2 3`)

If you're sure the file contains just 3 numbers, you can use [`read`](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html) to capture those into a variable, and then use your variable test code;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

read n1 n2 n3 < file.txt

echo $((n1 + n2 * n3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5ZCoMwGITfc4oBC2oLJS64QPHFG/QGUWMVNJH4S719mm4UCvM0Mx8zjVgHaz3URgqSILkT@nGSaLUiMapR3SB3MS/OUtvcSLMy2Q4afl6UWZ4lJc/TuEDKuRPniFIfVfXtnmknxjxcpeg@Hnqj598QM68ogoqhElz@yVpMLYTqsA76Dr3RstH7wSEIHHZ6gkeHhqG1Dw)

#### Numbers on seperate lines (`1\n2\n3`)

Set the [internal field separator](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line) to a newline, and read as stated above;

```sh
#!/bin/bash

{ IFS= read -r n1 && IFS= read -r n2 && IFS= read -r n3; } < file.txt
echo $((n1 + n2 * n3))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5LC4JAFIX3/opDRmhRTCU@qNwIQdvaupn0moLOxDiSEP12swdEBWf1ce93zpHXedeZiBRxTdDUamRFSUik0LwQhTiBWl6deySa6kiqNijJJaaEgecHrucuA@Y5Cz8WDmN9GIvF3BkgDJ@imW61YZjYE0/fBmRKVp8q44rd9rCBelxMFcQco9EPWvyj5Qo3rL86Il4m4CJFncsLZKPPjX6tHVpWr508ROP@1ba77g4) - [Additional info](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339992/how-to-read-different-lines-of-a-file-to-different-variables)

Comment: OP states the file contains `7896763907428 40040000 14` without any newlines?

Comment: This is a formatting problem - OP forgot to apply proper formatting to the file. And OP states that using `sed -n 2p` etc. he successfully gets the numbers, just the calculation doesn't work. Hm.. anyway, until OP comes, we will not know, so I'll run away. :p

Comment: Yea you're right, I guess OP needs to clarify. Stay tuned ;)

Comment: hey guys. After a day I found the problem. Initially there was newlines at the end of the numbers which I first removed using TR but ended using SED that skips \n while loading the value (I know by test and results). But the problem is indeed non printable character (or stuff). I had a text file type UTF8 with BOM. Changing to UTF8, bang! it worked. I came to that since any math that I did with the numbers on the file excluding the one on first line, worked just fine.

Comment: BTW, both suggestions above results on the same problem.